# Infinite nesting in java generics

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

Today I noticed that if you declare the following in Java:

```
public interface Foo<T extends Foo> {}
```

then you can recursively declare objects of the type:

```
Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo... ...>>>>>> foo;
```

and you will never hit the end of it, but you will never be able to satisfy the warning: "Foo is a raw type. References to the type Foo should be parameterized. Very curious.

Comment: What's the question? Anyway, `public interface Foo<T extends Foo> {}` would already give you that warning, before your declare any variable of this type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to get rid of the warning :

```
public interface Foo<T extends Foo<?>> {}
```

and

```
Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo<Foo<?>>>>>>> foo;
```

Answer (score 6):

The pattern is usually something like `interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>>`, then `Bar implements Foo<Bar>>`.

enums are a classic example. The base class is `java.lang.Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`, and an `enum MyEnum` is really a `class MyEnum extends Enum<MyEnum>`

Answer (score 3):

```
interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {}

class Bar implements Foo<Bar> {}
```

compiles without warnings because when `T` binds to `Bar`, `Foo<T>` binds to `Foo<Bar>` and since `Bar implements Foo<Bar>`, the `T extends Foo<T>` is fully satisfied.